The stablizer is closed when a topological group acts as a group of homeomorphism
I'm reading Berndt's book on representation theory. On page 33, after definition 3.3, the author said that, if G is a topological group, X is a Hausdorff space, G acts on X as a group of homeomorphism, then for each $x\in X$, the stablizer $G_x$ is a closed subgroup of G.
My proof of this propsition is as follows. If $(g_n)$ is a sequence of points in $G_x$ and has a limit point $g\in G$, then $gx = (\lim_{n \to \infty}  g_n)x = \lim_{n \to \infty}  (g_n x) = \lim_{n \to \infty}  x = x$. Hence $g\in G_x$. (The second equality comes from the fact that the action $G\times X \to X$ is continuous, thus it's continuous on the first variable, i.e., for given $x$, the function $g \mapsto gx$ is continuous).
The question is that I didn't use the condition that $X$ is Hausdorff, so there must be some mistake in my proof. But I can't find it. Please help me, many thanks!

Sequential closedness does not imply closedness. $G_x$ is the inverse image of the closed singleton ${x}$ under your continuous map $g\mapsto gx$.

Thanks for your help! I see my mistake, and the right proof should be that the single point in a Hausdorff space is closed. @anne

Indeed, whence my emphasis on this closedness of the singleton.
